# How to set hover effect continue show when mouse over hover elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have two main divs that have different css class. I want to show second div when i hover on  first div. Hover content showing fine but when mouse move hovered content. that div hide automatically.

**Here is my html content:**

```
<div class="cart_hover">XYZ</div>
<div id="header-cart" class="skip-content">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Here is my CSS classes:**

```
.cart_hover {

}
.show-content{
  display:block;
}
.skip-content {
  display:none;
}
```

**And Here is my jQuery:**

```
$(".cart_hover").hover(function(){
    $("#header-cart").addClass("show-content");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine..

```
$(".cart_hover").hover(function(){
    $("#header-cart").toggleClass("skip-content","show-content");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following signature of [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1) function,

```
var elem = $("#header-cart");
$(".cart_hover").hover(function(){
    elem.addClass("show-content");
  },function(){
    elem.removeClass("show-content");
  }
);
```

In your code, you have passed the `hoverIn` handler but not the `hoverOut's`. Also in css, the specificity for the class `.show-content` is lesser than the specificity of `.skip-content`. So increase it also to make the code working.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3o1e0q00/)

Comment: but I am not able to select list (hovered) elements

Comment: @BashkarJaved For that you have to modify your html. https://jsfiddle.net/3o1e0q00/1/

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/49/)**

You could use `toggleClass` to toggle between the both classes `skip-content` and `show-content` because `skip-content` will override the `display` of `show-content` :

```
$(".cart_hover").hover(function(){
    $("#header-cart").toggleClass("skip-content","show-content");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The hover() method specifies two functions to run when the mouse pointer hovers over the selected elements.

This method triggers both the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

If only one function is specified, it will be run for both the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

As your requirement is to display the div on mouseenter and that div should not hide then you can use following two example:

```
1) $(".cart_hover").mouseenter(function(){
$("#header-cart").css({"display" : 'block'});
```

});

```
2)$(".cart_hover").hover(function(){
$("#header-cart").css({"display" : 'block'});
```

}
);

jsfiddle code : https://jsfiddle.net/mallik_jahir/3o1e0q00/2/

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer provides a good solution to your jQuery. But have you considered a fully CSS implementation?

```
.cart_hover:hover + #header-cart, #header-cart:hover{
    display:block;
}
```

So long as header-cart comes directly after cart_hover, this will work without the need for a jQuery hover.

Comment: But I tried same css it is also behaving like jQuery example

Comment: I see - so you want the header-cart to stay visible when you stop hovering?

Comment: yes I want to so header-cart continue but when mouse out from header-cart. so header-cart div hide

Comment: I'm confused - that's exactly what the CSS above will do.

On hover of cart_hover, header-cart will appear. On mouseout of cart_hover, header-cart will hide.

Comment: On **cart_hover** mouse hover there same level div(**header-cart**) show and that div still open when my mouse coursor move from cart_hover to that div(**header-cart**). And when mouse out from div(**header-cart**) so that dive hide.

Answer (score 0):

So Final code will be like this and you can use xyz as a button.
Even you can use the CSS3 Transitions to make the menu smoothly.

```css
.cart_hover {
float:left;
background:#99CC00;
padding:10px;
}
.show-content{
  display:block;
}
.skip-content {
  display:none;
  float:left;
}

.cart_hover:hover + #header-cart, #header-cart:hover{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart_hover">XYZ</div>
<div id="header-cart" class="skip-content">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here "#header-cart:hover " helping the code to showing the menu during the second section hover.